# How to set fadeout or timeout to alert sucess & warning boxes in opencart 2.2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert, popupwindow, opencart2.x

I want to set timeout to alert boxes in opencart 2.2. It should disappear after some seconds. I was trying in this code, but didnt work out. Or is this possible if click anywhere in the page the popup should disappear? need help.

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // ALERT CLASS DEFINITION
  // ======================

  var dismiss = '[data-dismiss="alert"]'
  var Alert   = function (el) {
    $(el).on('click', dismiss, this.close)
  }

  Alert.VERSION = '3.3.5'

  Alert.TRANSITION_DURATION = 150

  Alert.prototype.close = function (e) {
    var $this    = $(this)
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
    }

    var $parent = $(selector)

    if (e) e.preventDefault()

    if (!$parent.length) {
      $parent = $this.closest('.alert')
    }

    $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('close.bs.alert'))

    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    $parent.removeClass('in')

    function removeElement() {
      // detach from parent, fire event then clean up data
      $parent.detach().trigger('closed.bs.alert').remove()
    }

    $.support.transition && $parent.hasClass('fade') ?
      $parent
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', removeElement)
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Alert.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
      removeElement()
  }


  // ALERT PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // =======================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.alert')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.alert', (data = new Alert(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.alert

  $.fn.alert             = Plugin
  $.fn.alert.Constructor = Alert


  // ALERT NO CONFLICT
  // =================

  $.fn.alert.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.alert = old
    return this
  }


  // ALERT DATA-API
  // ==============

  $(document).on('click.bs.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)

}(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some ugly code you got there. Are you sure `json` has the data and format you're expecting?

Comment: i have edited the code. check.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` is the class that opencart uses while displaying `error` or `success message`, go to `catalog/view/javascript/common.js`,

at the end of code add

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.alert').fadeOut() }, 5000);
```

you can change the time parameter based on your requirement.

Comment: Its not working buddy, you can visit to my website www.shreejifoods.in

Comment: I have added this code now its working in login, register, cart pages but its not working in category, home, product pages. any help from anyone.. please...